# Deadlock in SQL

Tags: sql, deadlock, pymssql

I have multiple python scripts that run in parallel and insert/update 2 tables.

```
Table 1: Nmap_Scans_Hosts
Table 2: Nmap_Scans_Ports
```

Both these tables have no PK, only a FK referencing a 3rd table `Nmap_Scans`.

When the scripts run, I get a deadlock on the tables. The scripts use `pymssql` and cursors for inserting/updating data.

The statements the scripts run are the following:

```
update lan.nmap_scans set latest = 0 where latest = 1 and target = '{target}'

INSERT INTO nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans

UPDATE nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Hosts SET Latest = 0 WHERE Host_Address = '{host_address}' and Tags = '{args.tags}'

INSERT INTO nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Hosts

UPDATE nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Ports SET Latest = 0 WHERE Host_Address = '{host_address}' AND Port is NULL

INSERT INTO nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Ports

update nvlanteam.lan.Nmap_Scans_Ports set Latest = 0 where Host_Address = '{host_address}' and Port = '{port_number}'

INSERT INTO nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Ports
```

The first 2 statements are only run once per script, while the other 6 are run in a loop for each ip address.

I tried setting `pymssql's autocommit = True` option but deadlocks still occur. Snapshot isolation is also enabled at database level.

Is there anything inherently wrong with my design? Or is there an option that I could enable that would prevent these deadlocks from occuring? Also, I know SQL Server kills one of the 2 deadlocked processes, but in my case, deadlocks are not resolved by SQL Server until I kill one of the Python processes.

Edit:
Included the DDL for the tables used.

```
CREATE TABLE nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans (
    Target varchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Hosts_Total int NULL,
    Hosts_Up int NULL,
    Scan_ID int IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    Scan_Server varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Scan_Command varchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Scan_Start datetime NULL,
    Scan_Finish datetime NULL,
    Elapsed int NULL,
    Latest bit NULL,
    Tags varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Nmap_Scans_PK PRIMARY KEY (Scan_ID)
);



CREATE TABLE nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Hosts (
    Scan_ID int NOT NULL,
    Host_Address varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Host_Name varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Region varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Country varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Location varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Division varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Subnet_Name varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    CIDR varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Reason varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    RTT float NULL,
    Latest bit NULL,
    Tags varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
);


-- nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Hosts foreign keys

ALTER TABLE nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Hosts ADD CONSTRAINT Nmap_Scans_Hosts_FK FOREIGN KEY (Scan_ID) REFERENCES nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans(Scan_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


CREATE TABLE nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Ports (
    Scan_ID int NULL,
    Host_Address varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Port int NULL,
    Protocol varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    State varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Reason varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Reason_TTL int NULL,
    Service_Name varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Service_Product varchar(500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Service_Version varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Service_Extra_Info varchar(1000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Device_Type varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Latest bit NULL
);


-- nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Ports foreign keys

ALTER TABLE nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans_Ports ADD CONSTRAINT Nmap_Scans_Ports_FK FOREIGN KEY (Scan_ID) REFERENCES nvlanteam.LAN.Nmap_Scans(Scan_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Please include the DDL for all table that are used in this question

Comment: "Is there anything inherently wrong with my design?" => Yes,  "Both these tables have no PK"

Comment: DDL included. Since there is no column that I would naturally assign a primary key to, should I create an identity column?

Comment: You should read about why someone invented to create an index on a table in a SQL database. There is a reason to do so, as there is a reason for creating a Primary Key.